# How is "se" used in the context of passive voice?

Tags: pronombres, español-neutral

How is "se" used in sentences with passive voice? For eg: The book is being read by me, Pizza is being delivered by her etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Se* cannot be used for a true passive, hence it's often called the fake passive for SSL students, because it's actually in active voice.

To take your sentences

- The book is being read by me.

  - **active** Yo leo el libro.
  - **passive** El libro es leído por mi.
  - **“se passive”** Se lee el libro (*por mí)
  - **“se passive” passive** El libro es leído por sí mismo.

Notice the issue is primarily in declaring agency. Because literally you are saying that *the book reads itself*, the literal passive (re)construction would be *the book is read by itself*, which excludes the possibility for other agents. Same with your pizza example.

- The pizza is being delivered by her.

  - **active** Ella está entregando la pizza.
  - **passive** La pizza está siendo entregada por ella.
  - **se passive** Se está entregando la pizza.

You can add many other details to the last bit, but not who is delivering it because adding *por ella* would, at best, be a slightly awkward way of saying she made the pizza that's being delivered, but not be interpreted as an indicator of agency. You have to leave it as a sort of anonymous passive (basically, English passive without the "by" prepositional phrase).